# How to scroll to bottom of the UITableViewCell instead of TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have a static `tableView` with one `textfield` in each `cell`. The cell height is 50. I have the following method to deal with keyboard:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Now, when I enter `textField`, if it is located under the keyboard, it automatically scrolls to the `textField`. Actually, I'm not sure how this is happening, since I'm not configuring this behavior anywhere. What is going on here?

And what I actually want is to scroll to the bottom of the `cell`, instead of `textField`. At the moment, it scrolls to the `textField` but it cuts off part of the `cell` and it doesn't look good.

The `contentInset.bottom` is right, since I can manually scroll to the last cell perfectly when keyboard is present.

I'm probably missing some native behavior.

Comment: This is the native behavior for `UITableViewController`s, FYI.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Can I override that and make it scroll to the bottom of `cell` ?

Comment: That, I'm not sure about. I'm actually wondering the same thing haha

Comment: What do you want to happen for cells that are in low rows, near the start of the table?

Comment: @danh on `UITableViewController`s, if the keyboard is showing, it will still bring the lower cells up above the keyboard.

Comment: For cells that are not under the keyboard, I don't want to do anything, and for the ones that are under the keyboard I want to scroll to the bottom of the row, not to the bottom of the `textField` as it is happening now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it something like this (not tested).  Figure out the cell's frame in the main view's coordinate system.  If the bottom of the cell below the top of the keyboard, adjust the table view's content offset by the difference...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = // get the cell containing the text field

CGRect bounds = [self.tableView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.view];
CGFloat cellBottom = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height;
if (cellBottom > kbSize.height) {
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:(cellBottom-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
}
```

There are several SO answers that can help you get the cell from the text field.  The best way is to walk up the superview pointers till you find a UITableViewCell. [Here's an example where I answered this for a collection view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340714/storyboard-parent-child-relationship-not-representing-what-is-returned-by-super)

Comment: Thanks, your code is great and it works, but I'm still getting a little difference. I mean, I'm missing something on the calculations because the bottom of the cell is not aligned with top of keyboard, the keyboard is still a little inside the cell, maybe a difference around 20-30. Not sure why. And the `setContentOffset: animated:` is not working, I had to animate it manually with [`UIView animateWithDuration...`

Comment: Hmm.  I wonder if your view is offset by the status bar.  If that were the case, the miss would be 20pts.  Maybe fudge that much and see if it works?  That will be evidence that it's related to view-status bar relationship.  Using UIView animation to move the table view rings a bell.  I think you've got that right.

Answer (score 0):

As @rebello95 said, this is the expected behavior in a UITableViewController. To avoid this, just inherit your view controller from UIViewController instead of UITableViewController and add the table view to the view by yourself.

Comment: That wouldn't be an option since I'm designing my `tableview` using `storyboard` and static `tableviews` work only with a `UITableViewController`. Right?

Comment: No. Everything you do with a UITableViewController you can do with a UIViewController. It just takes more setup : add a table view as a subview of your controller's view, and set your controller as the table views's delegate and data source.

Comment: I tried that, it seems the cells designed in storyboard don't work. The tableview works though, but I would have to design the cell programatically.